# Attaching a digiscope to a Raspberry PI

Tags: camera, wolfram-engine

I have a [digiscope](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07P413VRN/ref=pe_3187911_185740111_TE_item) arriving soon which has a Canon camera adapter included. I've a project in mind to mount a Raspberry Pi High Quality Camera onto the scope and rig up some image recognition software, possibly using Mathematica, to automate bird photography. Is it possible to mount a Pi 4 as I intend?

Comment: This sounds like a opto-mechanical structure question. [Raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/?resellerType=home) states the the RPI HQ Camera mount interface is C-mount though an adapter is provided for CS-mount. However you wouldn't interface this to your digiscope directly. - What lens are you using now to take photos? - What is the external mount interface on this lens (if it has)? - What is the lens/camera mount interface on the digiscope?

Comment: I have no setup at the moment, this will be brand new so I can't answer the first two questions. As for the third the Amazon details state "A smartphone digiscoping adapter, T-ring and M42 T mount for Canon camera"

Comment: the `digiscope` you linked consists of some lenses in a tube, nothing electrical ... you cannot connect the digiscope to the Raspberry Pi in any direct way, so your question is off topic here ... btw  it is a spotting scope ... why did you call it digiscope?

Comment: I am quite aware of what the digiscop is physically, thank you. If you look at the HQ camera module you will see it is a sensor backplate with an attachment for lenses to the front. It would seem using the mounting plate https://thepihut.com/collections/raspberry-pi-camera/products/mounting-plate-for-high-quality-camera you can mount high quality DSLRs onto a RPi. A digiscope is a spotting scope with an attachment to take a camera mounted on the eyepiece. The one I mentioned has adapters for smartphones and Canon DSLR as I said. The question remains what RASPBERRY PI HARDWARE do I need?

Comment: I do not think you will get an answer here.  Canon have many many mounts http://www.northlight-images.co.uk/canon-camera-mounts-and-change/ (and that's two years old).  Find out what the Digiscope has nativily as https://www.cliftoncameras.co.uk/all-brands-of-digiscoping-adapters lists 77 adapters then try to find a dealer who knows the scope and a Pi (or C / CS mounts).  My *GUESS* is you will need to pop the Pi lens off, fit the adapter and manually focus - I would not go adapter to adapter as the distance increases and you may not be able to adjust for that. Voted close for shopping request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having hunted around I found a Canon lens to C mount adapter which together with an adaptor provided with the scope enabled me to mount the scope as a lens on to the HQ camera. However, that was as far as it went. The image was black. It would seem the camera sensor is insufficiently sensitive, or the adaptor threw the focus out too much. Replacing the scope with a traditional telephoto lens was much more successful.